# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given while working with GUI

Tags: python-3.x

So, I am trying to make some basic functionality for my GUI. But I keep running into the same error:

TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. In the line:

```
frame = F(container, self)
```

I searched the web for about an hour but couldn't find anything that worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class MyClass(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, LoginPage, FiltersPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()
```

F stands for one of the pages of the app, the code below shows an example of one of the pages.

```
class StartPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.startMenu()

    def startMenu(self):
        heading = Label(self, text="My App", font=('Arial', 30))
        heading.grid(column=0, row=0)

        start_button = Button(self, text="Start", font='Arial 16', width=8, command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
        start_button.grid(column=0, row=1)

        exit_button = Button(self, text="Exit", font='Arial 16', width=8, command=self.controller.destroy)
        exit_button.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: what is `F` (`F(container, self)`) can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, F basically is the class for different pages of the application, and it takes some arguments, in this case, the container and the parent. I will show the code for one of the pages.

Comment: can you edit the question and also add `F` Class?

Comment: Yep just did that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just way too tired when I got this error, I completely forgot to set up one of the other classes, which messed up the for loop. So lesson learned: don't try to fix stuff when you are tired.